# Can we make some low quality tags synonyms, and outright remove some others?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

*Credit goes to [jokerdino](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) for making me aware of almost all of these tags. He sent me a list of tags he considered low quality, and asked me to post on meta about the ones I think we should take action about. Thus, this is really a collaborative effort. But this post reflects my viewpoint, so any blame and spam should be directed toward me. **;-)***

### Tags to Dupe

I think these tags should be made synonyms of other tags, as shown below.

- [recover](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recover) --> [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) **DONE**
- [impress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/impress) --> [libreoffice-impress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-impress) **DONE**
- [copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy) (134), [paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/paste) (25) --> [clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) **DONE**
- [custom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/custom) (31), [customize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/customize) (7)--> [customization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/customization) **DONE**
- [version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/version) --> [versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/versions) **DONE**
- [color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/color) (62), [colour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/colour) (11)--> [colors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/colors) **DONE**
- [pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pendrive) --> [usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive) **DONE**
- [menu-bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/menu-bar) (28)--> [panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/panel) **DONE**

### Tags to Remove

I think these tags should be untagged from all questions that have them, and perhaps even removed from the system ...but the more extreme step of having them blacklisted is probably not necessary.

- [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) (337): not very specific, used in different ways, and traps people into reporting bugs on AU
- [lag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lag) (**DONE**): used like "slow" this doesn't provide much information, at least as it's currently used
- [fun](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fun) (**DONE**): too meta, and not helpful to getting a question answered
- [close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/close) (**DONE**): is used mean way too many things, and even if we know which one, it's not sufficient tagging
- [tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tools) (39): mainly means "program" or "utility" which are too general, let's remove this, replacing with "software-recommendation" (only) where appropriate
- [utility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/utility) (**DONE**): too general (occasionally should be replaced with "software-recommendation")
- [features](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/features) (22): very meta, plus we don't have [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug) anymore, so no reason to have this either
- [editing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/editing) (27): too broad, we don't need a tag that means making changes to anything under any circumstances
- [multiboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiboot), [multiple-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multiple-boot) (**DONE**): I think we should remove these but keep dual-boot and triple-boot. If this is done, we can edit [triple-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/triple-boot)'s tag wiki so it explicitly includes questions about booting more than 3 OSes.

  - An alternative could be to get rid of [dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) and [triple-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/triple-boot).
  - But in practice, I think there really are a lot of special situations and considerations that come into play when you have three operating systems on one machine (especially if two of them are GNU/Linux systems or similar, and try to install GRUB by default).
- [connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connection) (214): we should retag this to [networking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/networking) or [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection) (or both), but this tag need not itself exist
- [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/workaround) (**DONE**): too meta -- doesn't give enough info about the question, and nobody can really be an expert in "workarounds" generally
- [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) (33): I'm sorry to see this has popped up again. Way too general. Let's remove...and maybe even ask for blacklisting.
- [lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lid) (33): I actually like this tag, but @jokerdino has expressed the view that it ought to be cleaned up, and I can definitely see that point of view. While [lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lid) is not the same as [suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/suspend), usually that or some other tag would apply.

### Tags to Rename

I'm not sure if it's possible to rename tags, but these tags have unfortunate names and would be better off with different names:

- [open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/open) (34) --> [opening-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/opening-files) (Doesn't exist yet)
- [corruption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/corruption) (11) --> [corrupted-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/corrupted-files) (0) (The one or two that are instead about graphics can just be retagged [screen-corruption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-corruption).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Done

- [recover](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recover) --> [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery)
- [impress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/impress) --> [libreoffice-impress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-impress)
- [copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy) (134), [paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/paste) (25) --> [clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) (42)
- [custom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/custom) (31), [customize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/customize) (7)--> [customization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/customization) (225)
- [version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/version) --> [versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/versions)
- [pendrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/pendrive) --> [usb-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb-drive)
- [color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/color) (62), [colour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/colour) (11)--> [colors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/colors) (62)
- [menu-bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/menu-bar) (28)--> [panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/panel) (282)
- [utility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/utility) (22): --> [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation)

### Done (Removed)

- [close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/close) (15): is used mean way too many things, and even if we know which one, it's not sufficient tagging
- [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/workaround) (5 - at least one of the question is locked): too meta -- doesn't give enough info about the question, and nobody can really be an expert in "workarounds" generally

Answer (score 4):

This is meta. Guys, speak up!

I say most make sense. Others, either I didn't look at them or probably I don't see the point yet. I trust *@jokerdino* to be a better judge regarding these issues, but can you people verify if the changes really make sense?

P. S: Look at the general pattern in questions tagged with a particular tag. *That* is what is to be accepted as its general usage.

@mods: Your comments are requested, and required. If we are talking of mass re-tagging, we'll probably need your supercow[1] powers and approvals.

[1]: intended to be a reference to some `man` page.