# Should the bar be higher to create tags...?

Tags: discussion, tags, privileges

This was [discussed before](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4127/can-we-increase-the-minimum-reputation-requirement-for-creating-new-tags) but no action was taken. I think this is still needed, since we have <s>2772</s> 2844 tags (9*4*<s>77</s> 79) and pretty much of them are kind of vague, doesn't define a particular topic, or the topic they define has nothing to do with Ubuntu. I've destroyed twice an attempt to create a [ubuntu-13.10] tag (BTW, the question was pretty generic, not even hw related) and the [14.04] which is still off-topic (remember that tags reflect what kind of questions can users asks, if we have a 14.04 tag it means that we *allow questions about 14.04*).

This and the apparent fact that most of users still doesn't know [when to create a tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D%20is%3aq%20create) support this fact. So, should we higher the bar for tag creation?

Comment: If even an 81k-user (me) disagrees with you about some tags, I don't think there's a limit high enough to sate your need for tag purity.

Comment: @Oli this was brought [in chat before I proposed it here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13093253#13093253), and the objective is that I could focus in organizing the existent tags instead of preventing the spread of bad tags. Also, you are mistaken about my objectives, I heavily rely on tags to look for questions to answer and if some question has bad tagging is our (yes, mine too) fault for not teaching users (reviewers) how to tag properly questions. I've created 10 tags thus far and each of them I give proper care.

Comment: I think there are still some situations where users can ask a question about a +1 Ubuntu, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate , but that is rare

Comment: @Mateo but +1 should be applicable to all +1's not just *that* +1 ;) (14.04 in this case). The answer will wither away and has no holdings in the time (like a bug).

Comment: I reckon a newly created should go through a process of approval from *a proper group of privileged*, who would also hold the responsibility to define the tag excerpt and the wiki, and then finally it should be available in the community's list of available tags..

Comment: I don't agree with a lot of your tagging opinions (along with some of the ones mentioned in this post) but the amount of stupid and meta tags we see created every day would warrant increasing this a bit I'd say.

Comment: @Seth funny thing is that there was almost community consensus before http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4127/can-we-increase-the-minimum-reputation-requirement-for-creating-new-tags and I agree with the post now for the same reason + what I described in this post