# Tag cleanup list

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

## We still need feedback on these tags!

**Esp. the "Not Sure" ones.**

I have started a list of tags that need some cleanup per request.  Please contribute.

**Burniate:**

[bits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bits)
[z475](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/z475)  [vm-guest-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vm-guest-files)
[slf4j](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/slf4j)  [binutils](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/binutils)  [ubuntu-secure-remix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-secure-remix)  [bluez](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bluez)  [fabric](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fabric) [garmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/garmin)  [off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/off) [googleplay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/googleplay)  [extended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/extended) [logical](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/logical) [latex-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/latex-editor) [hangout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hangout) [4k-video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/4k-video) [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash) [differences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/differences) [ubunu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubunu)  [fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fix)  [cpan-dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpan-dependencies)

**Not sure:**

[menu-bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/menu-bar) [nst](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nst) [reverse-tethering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tethering) [african-savanna](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/african-savanna) [brainstorm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/brainstorm) [cleanup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cleanup)  [photo-editing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/photo-editing)  [cover-art](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cover-art)

[administrator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/administrator) **-->** [administration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/administration)

[emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulator) **-->** [emulation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emulation)

**Synonyms**

[dependency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dependency) **-->** [dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dependencies)  **DONE**

[add-on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/add-on) **-->**  [plugins](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/plugins)

[aliased](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/aliased) **-->** [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/alias)

[bootable-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bootable-usb) **-->** [live-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-usb)  **DONE**

**Keep**

[parallel-port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/parallel-port) [cloning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cloning) [sagemath](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sagemath)

If you think a tag should stay please mention why.

When tags have no questions associated with them, they eventually get killed off.  No one seems to know how long that takes however (Discussion on that in [When do tags finally die?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167482/when-do-tags-finally-die)) which is why we need to make sure they don't have any questions.

Comment: Binutils and garmin... why remove those?

Comment: This was discussed in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8264585#8264585

Comment: [save](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/save) as a tag doesn't explain anything. I don't think it should exist - should be burniated.

Comment: parallel-port belongs in the same group as serial-port - both still existing pieces of hardware with probably very special problems - although not too frequent.

Comment: Either this or [that](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4039/can-we-make-some-low-quality-tags-synonyms-and-outright-remove-some-others) should probably be duped to the other.

Comment: @EliahKagan Probably that to this, seeing as this is newer.  Most of those tags are gone I think.  What do you think?

Comment: @Seth Sounds good to me. I have close-voted that.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see what's wrong with [binutils](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/binutils), but the point is moot since it's already been removed.

[parallel-port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/parallel-port) and [sagemath](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sagemath) are very obviously good tags about a specific kind of hardware or software. I'm puzzled as to how they got into your list.

Unix & Linux has a [cloning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloning) tag, about cloning a Linux installation. The tag seems worthwhile for Ubuntu too.

[sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sh) → [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash) strikes me as a bad idea since Ubuntu's `sh` is not bash. A question tagged [sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sh) is presumably about writing a `#!/bin/sh` script.

Comment: Well in that case I think [tag:sh] should be burniated.  Unless you think otherwise.

Comment: @Seth I don't see why, but it's a moot point, since [tag:sh] has already been burninated.