# Is the off tag really needed?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tags

I suddenly came across a question which had the [off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/off) tag. The tag itself has no explanation and I asked myself what the purpose of this tag is. From my perspective this tag is somehow confusing. Would it be better to rename it the something like `switching-off` or make an alias for [shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shutdown)? What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nah, just kill it.

The [off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/off) tag is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, and rhetorical and cannot be reasonably used.

I've added it to  of [Tag cleanup list](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6200/tag-cleanup-list).

Answer (score 6):

I've removed this tag from those few questions, hopefully it'll simply die on it's own.

Comment: Hopefully it'll be turned [tag:off].